# Ignore a base model in a Django ORM query

Tags: sql, django, orm

I have these models:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField()
    class Meta:
        pass

class Bar(Foo):
    some_other_field = models.CharField()
    class Meta:
        pass
```

<sup>The example is simplified, in reality both models have a lot of fields.</sup>

When I query Bar, the Django ORM creates a query containing an inner join with Foo.
I don't need the information in Foo.

**Question**: Is there a way to query Bar *without* an inner join with Foo?

I realize that removing Bar extending Foo and making it a foreign key would be a better way to solve this problem. However, there's a lot of legacy code relying on this so I'd prefer a quick solution until I have the time and guts to refactor legacy parts of the app.

I also realize I can write an SQL query myself, but I'd prefer a solution that uses the ORM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I've done it is to use a new unmanaged model for this instance

```
class SkinnyBar(models.Model):
    some_other_field = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "app_bar"
```

This will allow you to use the ORM.

If you want to avoid the duplication you could try adding most of your properties and methods to a meta class

```
class BaseBar(models.Model):
    some_other_field = models.CharField()

    def some_common_method(self):
        return True

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Bar(BaseBar, Foo):

    def some_method_that_requires_foo(self):
        return self.some_field == 1


class SkinnyBar(BaseBar):

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "app_bar"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this could work for me, but I still have an issue: I have a lot of fields and methods in my actual Bar model object, is there a way to add/mix these in SkinnyBar without duplication?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of doing this is making the Foo model abstract by adding abstract = True in the Meta. In your case, some_field is in the app_foo table and the join is needed in order to create the Bar object completely. If you don't need some_field, you can always drop to raw SQL. But in order to retrieve it, you must join app_bar and app_foo tables.

Comment: To clarify my question a bit: I don't need some_field in this case, but I do need to keep it working in all other (legacy) cases. Migrating both tables to one table is not something I want to do as the dataset is too big. — Are you sure there isn't a solution using the ORM?

Comment: Apart from raw query, no. The join is explicit. The object needs it to be complete.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting issue you have.

The inner join on it's own shouldn't be that big of a deal so long as your queries are setup appropriately. What is the main reason for trying to limit it, performance I assume? Can you post some code of how you're trying to work on these models?

I'm not positive this would work, but you could always look into using the '[defer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#defer)' function on your queryset. This function is really only for advanced use-cases, and may not apply here. In essence, defer doesn't try to query the fields you specify. if you defer'some_field', perhaps it won't do the join. The downside is that as soon as you try to access 'some_field' from the object, it will perform a query (iteration will cause n extra queries).

Comment: 1. Yes it is for performance. 2. Mainly using `Bar.objects.filter()` and `Bar.objects.get()`. 3. I have tried both `defer` and `only`, but for example `Bar.objects.all().only('some_other_field')` does not get rid of the inner join.